How to find out if WordPress is using GD or Imagick?
Wordpress is producing lower quality images when images are resized from Media -> Library -> Edit pages.
I've used following code in functions.php to force WordPress to use Imagick instead of GD.
add_filter( 'wp_image_editors', 'sm_force_imagick' );
function sm_force_imagick() {
    return array( 'WP_Image_Editor_Imagick', 'WP_Image_Editor_GD' );
}

On my dedicated server both GD and Imagick are installed.
How do we find out which image library WordPress is using?

you can see the choice in the code here : https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/6.7.1/src/wp-includes/media.php#L4228

That is the code, how do I verify what is the default on my WP installation?

Going off of @mmm's comment, you can use the wp_get_image_editor() function  to load up a file, and check the name of the object that's returned.
Additionally, the Query Monitor plugin lists the PHP extensions that are available, which can be used to see if GD and/or Imagick are available. If both are available, then the first one that claims to support editing of the image will be used.
